# Can we have an optional atrribute in a jstl tag depending upon another attribute?

Tags: java, tags, jstl

Earlier we had a tag `ifRole` such that

```
<op:ifRole role="role1">
   <li id="menu3SubMenu4">This will be shown only to the user with role1</li>
</op:ifRole>
```

In this tag we had one required field `role` and another optional field `secondaryRole`. Now I added another optional attribute `excluding` such that

```
<op:ifRole excluding="role2">
   <li id="menu3SubMenu4">This will be shown to all users except the one with role=role2</li>
</op:ifRole>
```

Also, I changed the attribute `role` from required to optional. Now, i don't want anybody to use this tag as:

```
<op:ifRole excluding="role2" role="role1">
```

This thing should not be allowed. One way is to throw the exception in `doStartTag` when both of these params are supplied. But I want other way round.

Comment: What do you mean "the other way round"?

Comment: @skaffman: i meant doing it using xml

Answer (score 3):

You can associate your tag with a `javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagExtraInfo` class, which can perform runtime validation of the attributes. This is perhaps a a cleaner way of doing this validation than doing it in the tag class itself.

The JavaEE tutorial covers it [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnann.html#bnanz)